# How do I intercept or elevate log messages when calling an Ant task from Gradle

Tags: ant, gradle

I call ant.signjar from a gradle script.
How can I capture its output?
I did neither get it managed easily to elevate the output from INFO to another level, nor to intercept or wrap the output to error warnings out to WARN level.
Currently the signjar echoes out that the certificate will expire soon, but this is not shown on WARN level which is not so nice.

Comment: As a side-note: Gradle provides the [signing plugin](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html) for signing artifacts so you don't need to use the Ant task.

Comment: @BenjaminMuschko I know about the signing plugin, but the documentation says it is only for generating PGP signatures of files e.g. for upload to Maven Central. How do I sign a JAR file with the signing plugin?

Answer (score 2):

I assume the Ant task is using Ant's logging framework, and not just printing to standard out. In that case, have you tried the following?

```
task taskThatCallsAntTask {
    logging.level = LogLevel.INFO
}
```

When configured in this way, the log level will be changed to INFO while the task is executing (and reverted back afterwards), no matter which log level is set when invoking Gradle. Note that you can't elevate the log level of an Ant log event; it's up to the Ant task at which level it logs.

Comment: That works, but then gives too much logging as it also prints other messages that are not warnings. I'd really prefer if I could intercept the output and elevate on a per-line scope. Any idea on that?

Comment: Did so at http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/interception_of_ant_task_output, thanks

Comment: This does not work with the daemon, see http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2273

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Can you set the logging level directly on an AntBuilder instance? The suggestion above is not working, but I get the output when '-i' enable for the build.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that captures the output of an Ant task by registering a custom BuildListener for the duration of the call.

```
def captureAntOutput(ant, Closure command) {
    def buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    def captureStream = new PrintStream(buffer, true, "UTF-8")
    def listener = new org.apache.tools.ant.DefaultLogger(
            errorPrintStream: captureStream,
            outputPrintStream: captureStream,
            messageOutputLevel: org.apache.tools.ant.Project.MSG_INFO
    )

    ant.project.addBuildListener(listener)
    project.configure(ant, command)
    ant.project.removeBuildListener(listener)

    return buffer.toString("UTF-8");
}
```

Example usage:

```
String result = captureAntOutput(ant) {
    echo(message: "hello")
}
assert result.contains("hello")
```