# Gradle: Get Ant Task Output

Tags: apache, ant, io, gradle, output

I have an Ant task that use the standard output to print information and I want use this output in a gradle task. I execute Ant task using following command:

```
tasks.myAntTask.execute()
```

Anybody know how can I get the Ant output and pass it to the gradle task?

Comment: Here's an interesting question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413559/how-do-i-intercept-or-elevate-log-messages-when-calling-an-ant-task-from-gradle.

Comment: Are you using Ant's `echo` command?  You can also use `println` from Gradle for output as well.  See this: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html#sec:import_ant_build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413559/how-do-i-intercept-or-elevate-log-messages-when-calling-an-ant-task-from-gradle) link may be helpful. Changing log level along with writing custom wrapper may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413559/how-do-i-intercept-or-elevate-log-messages-when-calling-an-ant-task-from-gradle)

Here's a method that captures the output of an Ant task by registering a custom BuildListener for the duration of the call.

```
def captureAntOutput(ant, Closure command) {
    def buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    def captureStream = new PrintStream(buffer, true, "UTF-8")
    def listener = new org.apache.tools.ant.DefaultLogger(
            errorPrintStream: captureStream,
            outputPrintStream: captureStream,
            messageOutputLevel: org.apache.tools.ant.Project.MSG_INFO
    )

    ant.project.addBuildListener(listener)
    project.configure(ant, command)
    ant.project.removeBuildListener(listener)

    return buffer.toString("UTF-8");
}
```

Example usage:

```
String result = captureAntOutput(ant) {
    echo(message: "hello")
}
assert result.contains("hello")
```